# Probability of an exact number of duplicate pairs when choosing X from Y.

Tags: probability

Here is the problem I'm faced with, as best as I can describe it.

There is a set of 256 values (a byte), and 108 values are chosen from this set. Each choice may be any value from 0 to 255. What is the probability that once the values are chosen, there will be **six** distinct pairs of duplicate values, and all other 96 values will be unique?

Comment: What's the relevance of having 256 values to pick from? Without knowing what they are I don't see what the question is really asking. Unless you're saying that you're generating 108 uniformly distributed integers between 0 and 255 inclusive, in which case this should be worded more clearly.

Comment: Are all $256^{108}$ choices equally likely?

Comment: Sorry, you're right in phrasing that I'm generating 108 uniformly distributed integers between 0 and 255 inclusive.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you change the question shortly after positing it or am I going mad?

Answer (score 1):

First let us compute the number of choices in a canonical order.  We list the pairs first in increasing order, then the single numbers.  There are $\binom {256}{6}$ ways to pick the pairs and $\binom {250}{96}$ ways to pick the singles.  Given a set of numbers, they can be ordered in $\frac {108!}{2^6}$ ways, as interchanging any of the pairs is equivalent.  The total probability is then $\frac {\binom {256}{6}\binom {250}{96}108!}{256^{108}2^6}\approx 6.5E-6$

Answer (score 0):

You have $6+96+154=256$ and $6\times 2 + 96 \times 1 + 154 \times 0 = 108$ so the probability you are looking for is

$$\frac{\frac{256!}{6!\;96!\;154!} \times \frac{108!}{(2!)^6\;(1!)^{96}\;(0!)^{154}}}{256^{108}} $$

Some more background on this approach can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23282/6460 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23696/6460

The numerical calculation may stretch some calculators.  I make it about  $6.54 \times 10^{-6}$.

Answer (score 0):

First I choose 102 distinct numbers, which can be done $256 \cdot 255 \cdot 254 \cdots 155 = \frac{256!}{154!}$ ways. Than I choose 6 numbers from these 102 previously choosen. Each of these 6 numbers will be paired with the same number. So I think the probability is $\frac{\binom{102}{6} \frac{256!}{154!}} {256^{108}}$.

Comment: I don't think your pairing works properly.  You have not selected where the second element of the pairs go in the series.  Also by your argument, the 108 should be 102.

Comment: You are right, I will try to modify my solution.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, we need to make some assumptions about the process of choosing. We assume that $108$ numbers are chosen "at random," one at a time, with replacement, from a set of $256$ numbers.

Imagine writing down the chosen numbers as a sequence of length $108$.
There are $256^{108}$ such sequences, all equally likely. This number will be the denominator of our probability.

Now we calculate the number of "good" sequences, that is, sequences that have exactly $6$ distinct pairs, and  $96$ singles.  The *types* of the pairs can be chosen in $\binom{256}{6}$ ways. Once we have settled on our $6$ types, imagine ranking the chosen types in some  arbitrary way, say numerical, but it doesn't matter.

Decide on the *locations* of the two numbers of the highest ranked type. This can be done in $\binom{108}{2}$ ways. For each of these ways, the locations of the two numbers of the next highest ranked type can be chosen in $\binom{106}{2}$ ways, and for each of these the locations of the two numbers of the next type can be chosen in $\binom{104}{2}$ ways, and so on.
So the full task of dealing with pairs can be done in
$$D=\binom{256}{6}\binom{108}{2}\binom{106}{2}\binom{104}{2}\binom{102}{2}\binom{100}{2}\binom{98}{2}$$
ways.

Now we have $96$ empty slots left.  The first can be filled in $250$ ways. For each of these ways, the second empty slot can be filled in $249$ ways, and so on. Finally, the $96$th empty slot can be filled in $250-96+1$ ways. So our task of filling the $96$ slots can be done in 
$$S=(250)(249)(248)\cdots(156)(155)$$
ways.

So the number of ways we can have $6$ distinct pairs and the rest singles is $DS$.
For the probability, divide $DS$ by $256^{108}$.