# Dice-Game Probability

Tags: probability, dice

In many dice-games throwing 2 (3, 4...) of a kind or special combinations are meaningful events.

I am wondering how to approach the following problem:

Given **d** dice with **s** sides each. Of those **s** sides **h** sides count as a hit. The amount of hits shown after throwing the dice is **n**.

Searched is the probability for throwing a) **n** hits and b) **n** hits or (not exclusive) **m** hits with **1 < m < n**.

Example with numbers: You got 10 dice with 6 sides each. How big is the chance to get exactly 4x "6" and how big to get 4, 3 or 2x "6".

It's related to [this SE- post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953400/probability-of-rolling-exactly-4-of-a-kind-on-6-dice), but different.

I'm struggling to generlize the problem. Given 2 dice with 6 sides of whose 1 counts as a hit I got 1-(s-h/s)^d aka 1-(5/6)² and for given a bigger d I can use the Binomial coefficient to get all valid combinations (d! / (n! * (d-n)!)) but the whole clean formula is eluding me right now.

In case this makes any difference: This is no school-homework, I'm simply trying to balance a dice-game to play with some friends. I knew this back in school, but it's long gone now. I'm really grateful for any advice as it drives me crazy right now. :(

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Please have a look at this [formatting reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).